# Calculate the derivate $(1+2x)^3$ with the definition

Tags: derivatives

I need to calculate $(1+2x)^3$ in $f'(0)$ using the definition.
I'm able to show how arrive to:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h}$$

but I do not understand how should I procede to calculate it in $f'(0)$, how should I do?

Shoul I use: $f(x_0+h) = (1+2(x+h))^3$?

Comment: First you calculate $f'(x)$, then you plug in $x=0$. All inbetween is straight up calculation.

Comment: Word usage ... "Differentiate," not "derivate."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+2h)^3-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}(6+12h+8h^2)=6$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate $f'(0)$, simply find
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{(1+2(h+0))^3-(1+2(0))^3}{h}$$
which is simplified to
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{(1+2h)^3-1}{h}$$

Answer (score 0):

No that's not it. Replace $x$ with 0 in the limite, not $h$. 
Other way to do it is to use the equivalent definition $$f'(a)=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$ Just do $a=0$.